# Can anyone provide me a hint for finding the limit involving a factorial function?

Tags: limits

I have to find the limit of this function:
$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{(n!)^{2}}{(2n)!}$

Can anyone provide a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have factorials, Stirling approximation $$n!\approx \sqrt{2\pi n}\,n^n \,e^{-n}$$ is very useful. So for your case $$\frac{(n!)^{2}}{(2n)!}\approx \frac{\sqrt{\pi n}}{2^{2n}} $$

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:**
$$\frac{\frac{(n+1)!^2}{(2n+2)!}}{\frac{n!^2}{(2n)!}}=\frac{(n+1)^2}{(2n+2)(2n+1)}=\frac{n+1}{4n+2}\xrightarrow[n\to +\infty]{}\frac{1}{4}. $$

Comment: @Soke The answer is not zero. Surprised?

Comment: @Crostul Am I missing something here? Isn't this just the reciprocal of ${2n \choose n}$? Am I reading the question wrong?

Comment: Yes, the answer is zero, **why though?**. The hint points towards *infinite series* ...

Comment: Oh I see. This is the ratio test. Sorry it's too late here lol.

Answer (score 2):

This answer was inspired by a remark of @Soke: $\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}$ is the  reciprocal of the binomial coefficient $\binom{2n}{n}$.

There are $n$ couples in a room. We wish to choose $n$ **people**. There are $\binom{2n}{n}$ ways to do this.

There are $2^n$ ways to choose $1$ person from each couple. It follows that $\binom{2n}{n}\ge 2^n$.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), which makes the limit

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {{2 \pi n}(\frac{n}{e})^{2n}}{\sqrt{4 \pi n}(\frac{2n}{e})^{2n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{\pi n}}{2^{2n}}=0$$

Comment: Same idea ! Sorry since I suppose that your answer came while I was typing. $+1$. Cheers

Comment: Yes, our answers were almost written at the same time. $+1$ to you too! Stirling approximation just kills factorials.  Cheers